# AJAX запрос на Yii

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, yii

Добрый вечер. Подскажите, как отправить правильно AJAX запрос в Yii?
Делаю вот так:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            // send ajax
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json", // Тип данных, который ожидаем получить
                url: "../my/counts", // url where to submit the request
                success: function (result) {
                    var barChart = new Chart(popCanvas, {
                            type: "line",
                            data: {
                                labels: result.map(item = > item.title),
                        datasets
                :
                    [{
                        label: "Посещения",
                        data: result.map(item = > item.visits
                ),
                }]
                }
                })
                    ;
                },

                error: function (xhr, resp, text) {
                    console.log(xhr, resp, text);
                }
            })
        }
    );
```

Мне пишет, что по такому пути нет ничего.
В папке `controllers`  лежит контроллер `MyController` в котором `actionCounts`. Может путь как-то не так указываю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый вечер.
Делайте путь к действию контроллера при помощи yii\helpers\Url

```
url: <?= Url::toRoute('controller/action') ?>
```

Или формируйте переменную с путём заранее и подставляйте в jquery.
Подключайте через registerJs, так будет проще.

```
$this->registerJs("
   $.ajax({
      url: '".Url::toRoute('controller/action')."'
   })
", yii\web\View::POST_END)
```

Comment: url: <?= Url::toRoute('my/counts') ?>. Пишет: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags. В F12 вот что выходит: /web/index.php?r=my%2Fcounts

Comment: Во-первых, включите чпу. Во-вторых, где именно у Вас располагается jquery?

Comment: Первое - не знаю, как это делается. Второе - /web/js/jquery.js

Comment: Про чпу https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/runtime-routing.md#%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-url-  Перенесите свой js код в php файл, как я показал.

Comment: У меня js код и так в php файле

Comment: Вы же написали, что он у Вас тут /web/js/jquery.js

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73993/discussion-between--and-slo-nik).

Comment: уже перешёл в чат